# Chrome search history not fully cleared

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am encountering a really strange behavior with Google Chrome.

In the Google Chrome Address Bar (where you can type in search term or URL), it will remember the history of the search and pages. However, when I run a "clear all history." It cleared almost everything except a few URLs and a few searches. This makes those few histories in the address bar "undeletable".

Since it is synchronizing this across my devices as well, the undeletable entries (less than 6 entries) also appear in my mobile phone Chrome as well.

Here's what I've done (with my Google Account logged in using Chrome)

- Clear history in Chrome with time range **All time** and select **Browsing history & Cookies and other site data**
- Go to myactivity.google.com/myactivity and click on **Delete activity by** and choose **All time**, and for products, I only checked **Chrome, Search**.
- Restart the browser

At this point, when I type something into the Chrome address bar, the undeletable entry still shows up.

Any idea what am I missing?

This shouldn't be this difficult, but I couldn't figure it out and did a lot of searches online, cannot really find a solution to this.

Any help will be fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

OK,

I figured it out. I'll leave my answer here so other people who encounter this similar problem know what's going on.

Basically, the Google Chrome address bar will auto-complete history AND any bookmark that you have.

So that means when I clear all "history" (which it did clear successfully), but if I have it in my bookmark, it will still show up in the address bar auto-complete option.

So regardless of how many times you clear history (which once is enough), as long as you have it "bookmarked", it will show up. There's no easy way to tell if the suggestion is a "bookmark" or a "history".

If you are in the same situation, I hope this answer will help you.

Thank you!